# Converting a Python function to PL/Python function

Tags: python, postgresql, numpy

I have written a couple of python functions to do Power transformation of a continous variables in a dataset. The first function basically finds the data type of each column and returns a dict of data types along with corresponding columns names as values.

The second function now takes this dict of data types and column names and takes an input dataset and does a power transformation of each continuous feature('float64') using the power transformation function written in the code.

It works all well in python. Here is the code for that:

## First pass your dataset to featuresDtypes function to get the data type of variables as a dict.

```
# Then pass the same dataset to varTransformation function by also passing the returned data type dict. 


def featuresDtypes(model_data1):
    """This function takes a dataframe and gives a dict of column
    data types

    """

    g = model_data1.columns.to_series().groupby(model_data1.dtypes).groups
    var_types={k.name: v for k, v in g.items()}
    return var_types



def varTransformation(model_data1,var_types):
    """This function takes in a list of continuous feature names
    and transforms it using Box-Cox transformation

    list--> df
    (list of feature names)---> returns a transformed pandas dataframe
    """
    var_transform_mapping={}
    model_data_transformed=copy.deepcopy(model_data1)
    continuous_var=var_types['float64']
    for x in continuous_var:

        # Anchoring the data at 1 as Box-Cox takes more than 0 as the value
        model_data_transformed[x]=(model_data_transformed[x]-(model_data_transformed[x].min()-1))
        lmbda,ppc=sp.stats.boxcox_normplot(model_data_transformed[x], -20, 20, plot=ax)
        lmax_pearsonr = sp.stats.boxcox_normmax(model_data_transformed[x])
        lamda_ppc=lmbda[ppc.argsort()[::-1][0]]
        #Rounding the lambda value
        if 0.3<=np.abs(lamda_ppc)-int(np.abs(lamda_ppc))<=0.59 :
            lamda_ppc=cmp(lamda_ppc,0)*(int(np.abs(lamda_ppc))+0.5)
        else:
            lamda_ppc=cmp(lamda_ppc,0)*(np.around(np.abs(lamda_ppc)))


        # Getting the box - cox tranformation using the lambda value
        model_data_transformed[x]= sp.stats.boxcox(model_data_transformed[x],lamda_ppc)
        var_transform_mapping[x]=lamda_ppc

    return model_data_transformed,var_transform_mapping
```

Now I want to implement this in PL/Python for Postgresql.

Basically I am looking for something like below:

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION  Powertransform(dataset table)
    RETURNS table AS
$$

<Python code here (as used above) for powertransformation>

$$ LANGUAGE 'plpythonu';
```

Within this PL/Python we can use the Information schema code to get the data type of each column in a postgres table. So we do not need the first python function written above which does the same but in python format. The remaining part of the Pl/Python code would be similar where on seeing if a column belongs to continuous type then transform it using PL/Python.

The final returned table I need a modified/transformed table of variables along with a dict or mapping of column names transformed with the correct transformation value as shown in python function.

Any help?